# How to add the options of a drop down in ajax

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

Please help as am unable to add options to a select menu. The data is in a string form of the type ~~. So here I am splitting the data and then looping it through the length of the data and setting it against the options.

Below is the ajax code

```
function showCircle() {

          alert("Microsoft");

         xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handleStateChange;
      xmlhttp.open("POST", "GetCircleDetails" , true);

          xmlhttp.send();
        }

    function handleStateChange() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                alert("The server replied with: " );
                var splits21 = xmlhttp.responseText.split("~");
                var select = document.getElementById("circle");
                var opt = document.createElement("option"); 
                var i = 0;
                for (i = 0 ; i < xmlhttp.responseText.length ; i++)
                    {
                    opt.valueOf(splits21[i]);
                select.appendChild(opt);
            }


              alert("The server replied with: " +xmlHttp.responseText);
            }
```

Below is the HTML tags used.

```
<select  name="slabFrom" onchange="showCircle(this.value)">
<option>--select--</option>
<option>slab1</option>
<option>slab2</option>
<option>slab3</option>
<option>slab4</option>

</select> 

</br>
</br>
The circle is:<select  id= 'circle' name="circle" >
```

Comment: Is the request successful or do you get an error response code?

Comment: request is successful.. I am even getting the data to the jsp page.. but am unable to add those data as options to the second drop down menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a couple of corrections in `handleStateChange` function:

1) change what you iterate in `for` to `splits21`instead of `xmlhttp.responseText`.

2) move `var opt = document.createElement("option");` into the `for` iteration

3) change `opt.valueOf(splits21[i]);` to `opt.value = splits21[i];`

4) add closing tag to `select` in html: `<select id='circle' name="circle"></select>`

Check demo - [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrXRZb).

```
function handleStateChange() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    var splits21 = xmlhttp.responseText.split("~");
    var select = document.getElementById("circle");
    var opt;

    for (i = 0; i < splits21.length; i++) {
        if (splits21[i]) {
          opt = document.createElement("option");
          opt.innerHTML = splits21[i];
          opt.value = splits21[i];
          select.appendChild(opt);
        }  
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you use the above code or the one in codepen? You should use the one above. The rest depends on what you have in `xmlhttp.responseText`, it just gets split into array and added to `select`. What other values do you mean?

Comment: Got it. Then just wrap the code inside `for` into `if (splits21[i]) {...}`. I updated answer.

Comment: Got it... Thank you so much!!

Comment: I thought I could accept both answer's.... because both worked... :D....  now done :)

Comment: Nikolay.. here the second drop down is dependent on first drop down and if I re-select the first drop down the new values are getting appended to the old values in second drop down.. please help..

Comment: Just add `select.innerHTML = '';` before iteration. Look here - http://codepen.io/ermakovnikolay/pen/Wwrqeg

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'd move your option variable in to the for loop. Whilst I don't know what else is going wrong with your code, using the following method works - (this is with hard coded variables for testing, swap them for the split variables retrieved from your ajax) -

var selectValues = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];

```
function handleStateChange(){
  var select = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];

  for(var i = 0; i < selectValues.length; i++){
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.text = selectValues[i];

    select.appendChild(option);

    console.log(selectValues[i]);
  }
}
```

Fiddle here -

https://jsfiddle.net/8pqq82eq/

Comment: Got it... Thank you so much!!